# How to copy files recursively from multiple folders of a certain extension eg .pes to another folder in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, node.js-fs

I have a folder that has about 112000 items. Of those items there are folders and subfolders and in the subfolders there are files that I need to be able to copy of a certain extension eg .pes
I can recursively get all the files I need in an array, however trying to copy those files to another folder is the problem, can anyone please assist?

I have only managed to get all the files I require in an array, need help to copy this array of files to another folder.

UPDATE: I have managed to solve this issue here is the README.md explanation on my github page (https://github.com/djmuller-python-43/copy_files_recursive) which has the updated code.

## copy-files-recursive ·

### This program helps you to copy files from a nested folder structure eg PICS folder.

#### Built With

This program is written in JavaScript using Node.JS.

The following modules are imported:

1. [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra)
2. [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)
3. [recursive-readdir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-readdir)

#### How it works

- Lets say you have a folder and inside that folder you have some subfolders which can have files.
- Now lets say you are looking for a type of file, like in my case was '.pes'.
- You would first then need to loop over all folders and subfolders to get the path to all the files.
- This is where [recursive-readdir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-readdir) comes in, you pass in a source directory and it does the rest.
- Once you have that list of file paths, which will be an array.
- You need to loop through that array using the filter() method, looking for that file format eg '.pes'.
- Then copy those files to another folder eg PES
- This program does all that for you.
- All you need to do is provide the file format in the includes('.pes'),
- which is then filtered to only produce the files with '.pes' extension.
- The copyFileSync() method has 2 arguments src, dest.
- The variable fn is the source and, path.join('./PES', '/', path.basename(fn)) is destination.

```
const recursive = require("recursive-readdir");
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const path = require('path')

recursive("./PICS", function (err, files) {
  // `files` is an array of file paths
  const filteredFiles = files.filter((file) => file.includes('.pes'))
  
for (const fn of filteredFiles) {
  
  fs.copyFileSync( fn , path.join('./PES', '/', path.basename(fn)) ); 
}
});
```

Comment: You can add your code as an answer and explain how it works, in order to possibly help others in the future.

Comment: Does the target structure need to reflect the source structure (ie create the same subfolders) do you want to copy in a single folder?